# Use SES (with SNS) over SMTP

Tags: amazon-web-services, smtp, amazon-sns, amazon-ses

I have an little application that uses SMTP already.
And in the future i want switch to AWS SES and use it via SMTP. 
In AWS SES i will use a AWS SNS for bouncing mails.

Is it a problem, when i use SES over SMTP with an SNS for bouncing, because i found this part in the documentation:

> Email Information to Provide
>
> When you access Amazon SES through the SMTP interface, your SMTP
>   client application assembles the message, so the information you need
>   to provide depends on the application you are using. At a minimum, the
>   SMTP exchange between a client and a server requires a source address,
>   a destination address, and message data.
>
> If you are using the SMTP interface and have feedback forwarding
>   enabled, then your bounces, complaints, and delivery notifications are
>   sent to the "MAIL FROM" address. Any "Reply-To" address that you
>   specify is not used.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_en/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/send-email-smtp.html

Now i have some doubts that when i switch to SES SMTP i must handle the bouncing on my own and the SNS will be ignored. Is this right or is SNS always used? (Via API and SMTP)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SNS to handle complaints and bounces, you can disable email notifications.

See step 6 here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/configure-sns-notifications.html

> If you choose Amazon SNS topics for both bounces and complaints, you
>   can disable email notifications entirely. To disable email
>   notifications for bounces and complaints, under Email Feedback
>   Forwarding, choose Disable. Delivery notifications are available only
>   through Amazon SNS.

Comment: When i am disable it, is this the same for access via AWS API and SMTP or is there a disadvantage over SMTP?

Comment: Email notifications will be disabled regardless of how the messages are sent.